# Bulk Validation in SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a excel sheet that will have 18,000 Id's. We have a Master table in our database where these Id's in the excel sheet is available.

Since it's a excel sheet modified by many users we want to validate those 18,000 Id's and make sure it's a valid Id avilable in the database. But we don't want to call a procedure by passing one Id at a time and validate the Id. This way we have to make 18,000 DB calls to validate all 18,000 IDs so we don't wnat that.

Is there any other recommeded way to acheive this?

**I Tried This:**
Passed all 18,000 Ids as table valued parameter to a procedure.
Used SQL Merge Concept. 
Target Table : Master Table which has all the IDs.
Source Table : Table valued parameter.
Condition : ON TargetTable.id = SourceTable.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
-- Here I don't want to update, delete or INSERT in to my target table because that's our master table so we don't want any DML statements aganist that table. But SQL Merge is not letting me to work with other tables here. So this is not working for me.

Comment: 1st bring all your data in sql server in a stagging table then filter out the unwanted rows by (joining/Merge) whatever suits you and then do the operations with the all filtered rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to do this is to bulk import to a temp table, then join that table via the ID in excel and ID of your reference table.  Anything joined will be the Valid ones and not joined will be the invalid ones.

Valid ones

```
SELECT * FROM ExcelDump inner join ReferenceTable on ExcelDump.Id = ReferenceTable.Id
```

Invalid ones

```
SELECT * FROM ExcelDump inner join ReferenceTable on ExcelDump.Id <> ReferenceTable.Id
```